# Is there anything I can do other than have an Honorable Death?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

In multiplayer for *Assassins Creed: Revelations*, I'm wondering if there's anything I can do other than counter another assassins attempt on my life and take an Honorable Death. If I time the counter better and manage to get it in time, can I truly counter the other assassin and kill them, or is Honorable Death the only possible outcome?

I am aware of stunning them if I can sneak up on them without them detecting me and making an attempt on my life, I'm looking for a true counter to their attempt.

Comment: Greetings from the comment fairy. I'm considering getting this game... it's fun si?

Comment: @SeanGallagher If you haven't played other Assassin Creed's, I suggest doing that first. I'm finding this one more frustrating than the others in various ways... but details are probably best reserved for [chat]. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll be looking at this from a deathmatch perspective.  Other game types is much more difficult to do this and they're not the big focus in the game (particularly with team game types).

Line of Sight, it can be a blessing or it can be a curse.  Master this (or get good enough controlling this) and you will be more successful in the game.

First of all, let me point out something that could save you a *lot* of grief.  Don't make the same mistake I did and play the game with reduced music volume.  The way the game is, certain classes of sounds are controlled by the music volume.  You'll notice this definitely with the videos that play.  What you probably won't notice is that the pursuer whispers are also grouped with the music volume.  If you play with reduced volume (I don't know if this is the case for with it completely off), you are going to have a tough time knowing if you should be playing defensively when a pursuer is around.

First things first, you need to identify your pursuer.  You need to be aware at all times who your opponents are and what personas they are using.  If you joined a game that started off small (4 players), you should periodically check the scoreboards so you can see how many are still in the game (people can leave or join at any time and you don't really notice the messages) and what personas to look out for.

When you hear the whispers, you should look for any player (this is where knowing which personas to look for helps) in your line of sight that remotely looks like they are trying to move closer to you, starting with the ones closest to you.  Study every player in your vicinity long enough and try to figure out, where are they trying to move.  You can't really do this one at a time, you have to look at *everyone* all at the same time.  If you're a little slow or don't have the time to do this, target the nearest player around you and spam the stun button when they're close.  If it was a pursuer, you will have a stun or contested kill.  Otherwise if it wasn't, then nothing will happen (you cannot stun non-pursuers).

Once identified, you need to find a way for you to break their line of sight off of you while keeping them in your field of view.  The best way to do that is to stand at a corner, behind a large pillar or divider so that you can hide behind while you can turn the camera to keep an eye on them.

Use your abilities if given the opportunity and it can help you.  If you are able to hit them with it, try to run behind them and stun them (I find that running up in front almost always gets a contested kill if they are aware of you).  You won't need to do this if you use smoke bombs or other abilities that completely incapacitates them.  Otherwise, try to catch them at the corner where you're standing.  Their view will most likely be from behind them and won't see you until after they round the corner.  You could see them approaching and can usually get the upper-hand with your stun or in the rare cases, a guaranteed honorable death.

Comment: You can't stun non pursuers, but you can stun civilians, which makes you stand out even more. So spamming the button might not be the best of ideas :-)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to not get killed is if your opponent can't press kill when you press the humiliation.

So you have to:

1. Take him by surprise.
2. Make him unable to kill you during that time (e.g. with a smoke bomb).

Answer (score 1):

You'll mostly get an honourable death if:

- The attacker is running towards you.
- They have you in a lock (lasts for 3-5s after you break line of sight)
- The attacker has you in front of them.
- You seem to get slightly longer to attack than stun, but that might be a lag issue.

You'll mostly get a stun if:

- They're blocked by smoke, mute, or similar.
- They're stumbling from a failed crowd bash.
- They're mid taunt, attack or grounded attack.
- You're behind them and they haven't got a lock on you.
- They've been waiting for the Focus attack timer to fill.

Finally you usually don't even get a chance to block (even if you spot them) if:

- They're going for a grab (under a ledge), aerial or acrobatic kill.
- They're behind you.
- You're mid action (attack, taunt, etc)

If they've spotted/locked you and are heading your way then you can run (which means they'll end up with a measly 100 for the kill at best) or hit them with a smoke bomb/mute (abilities unlocked somewhere round levels 15-20) and then stun them.

As the game is about score rather than number of kills I find run is often the best reaction - you'll get more score for successfully escaping than they will even if they catch you.

Comment: I concur.  It looks like you need to catch them off guard completely (or use an ability) to be able to pull of a clean stun.  It's not necessarily who attacks first but whether or not you both notice each other and press at roughly the same times.